# How can I implement a reset on behaviours in my behaviour tree

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have created a simple behaviour tree in godot using nodes, I have created the basic stuff that is needed in a behaviour tree, root, selector, sequence I also have leaf and condition nodes, now the issue I am facing is that when I have two sequences and one takes over the other the first sequence still has its previous data, for example a patrol leaf in my code makes it move to a random position and wait a few seconds but if another sequence takes over and goes back, it remembers its last goal target, I prefer it to reset and choose a new position instead, I have added a reset behaviour function in the base node so I can override it in their own leaf and conditional nodes but I am not sure where I should call such a function and I attempted putting the function in the sequence class if its success or failure reset but that caused some unwanted issues for example, I have a wait node that simply waits a few seconds before continuing to the next leaf, and calling reset would make it stay in the wait node.

Base class:

```
class_name NodeBT extends Node2D

enum NodeState {RUNNING,SUCCESS,FAILURE}
var State : NodeState

func Evaluate(Data : DataTreeClass) -> NodeState:
    return NodeState.FAILURE

func ResetBehaviour() -> void:
    pass
```

Root:

```
class_name RootBT extends NodeBT

@onready var DataTree = DataTreeClass.new()

func _ready() -> void:
    DataTree.Set("Actor",get_parent())

func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    DataTree.Set("delta",delta)
    self.get_child(0).Evaluate(DataTree)
```

Selector:

```
class_name SelectorBT extends NodeBT

var SelectorChildren : Array

func _ready() -> void:
    SelectorChildren = get_children()
    
func Evaluate(Data : DataTreeClass) -> NodeState:
    for child in SelectorChildren:
        var childState = child.Evaluate(Data)
        
        match childState:
            NodeState.FAILURE:
                continue
            NodeState.SUCCESS:
                return NodeState.SUCCESS
            NodeState.RUNNING:
                return NodeState.RUNNING
            _:
                continue
                
    return NodeState.FAILURE
```

Sequence:

```
class_name SequenceBT extends NodeBT

var SequenceChildren : Array

func _ready() -> void:
    SequenceChildren = get_children()

func Evaluate(Data : DataTreeClass) -> NodeState:
    for child in SequenceChildren:
        var childState = child.Evaluate(Data)
        
        match childState:
            NodeState.FAILURE:
                return NodeState.FAILURE
            NodeState.SUCCESS:
                continue
            NodeState.RUNNING:
                return NodeState.RUNNING
            _:
                return NodeState.SUCCESS
                

    return NodeState.RUNNING
```

Patrol Leaf:

```
class_name PatrolAction extends NodeBT

@export var Speed : int
var TargetPosition : Vector2
  
func _ready() -> void:
    NewTarget()

func Evaluate(Data : DataTreeClass) -> NodeState:
    var Actor = Data.Get("Actor")
            # Move towards the target position
    Actor.velocity = (TargetPosition - Actor.position).normalized() * Speed
    Actor.move_and_slide()

    # Check if the Actor has reached the target position
    if Actor.position.distance_to(TargetPosition) < 5.0:
        Actor.position = TargetPosition
        NewTarget()

        # Return success when the patrol is completed
        return NodeState.SUCCESS

    # Return RUNNING while the patrol is in progress
    return NodeState.RUNNING

func NewTarget():
    TargetPosition = Vector2(randi_range(100,900), randi_range(100,450))

func ResetBehaviour() -> void:
    print("Restarted")
    NewTarget()
```

Comment: You say you have "a patrol leaf in my code makes it move to a random position and wait a few seconds" can you not make it forget its target once it reached it (or failed to reach it)?

Comment: @Theraot I understand what you are saying but my patrol leaf does not fail, its either returning running or success, also I'm not sure how it could fail, if you like I can add the patrol script to show you how I have done it.

Comment: oh and also it finds a new target when it reaches its location of course it never does if another sequence takes over.

Comment: Does it change targets without going into success state? Is the other node taking over while the behavior is in running state? Yeah, probably the code for the leaf will answer all the questions.

Comment: I have included the patrol leaf, the wait leaf is separate and all it does is wait a few seconds only returning running or success, hope this can help you understand what I am doing, or maybe I am not doing this correctly, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your sequence and selector iterate over their children, which is correct. And when they reach a node that return running, they return running, which is correct.

And on the next frame, they does the same, which means it iterates over their children... From the start.

As a result, a node that returned running might not finish (complete or fail).

---

I suggest to modify the sequence and selector to remember when they returned running, so they can resume from the same node instead of starting over.

However, be aware that it would require more work to handle the case where the code that is running is removed at runtime.

This is what comes to mind:

- Store a reference to the node that is running.
- If the reference is not valid (check with `is_instance_valid`) then start from the beginning and set the reference to `null`.
- If it is not a child (check by checking `get_parent`) start from the beginning and set the reference to `null`.
- Otherwise, find where in the list of children it is (you can use `get_index`), and start from there.